# Why do I keep getting a "missing \begin{document}" error?

Tags: errors, debugging

[image]
Sorry about the awful formatting, this is a screenshot from my mobile. 
I am an absolute beginner when it comes to Latex and I just can't understand why it keeps giving me such an error when I clearly included " /begin{document} "
Could you help me fix this.
Thanks a bunch

Comment: If possible, could you please paste in the actual code, rather than a screenshot, to allow others to test the code themselves. Also, please trim out as much extraneous code as possible while still retaining the error.

Comment: `\thanks{...}` should be inside the argument to `\author` not after it,

Comment: You should add `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` to get proper hyphenation in the output pdf.

Answer (score 3):

`\thanks{...}` should be inside the argument to `\author` not after it,

Please always provide a test file, like

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{zzz}
\author{You}\thanks{me}
\date{now}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Note that the error message is not just "missing document" it highlights the line with the error, and shows (by the point of the linebreak) that the error is reported just after reading `\thanks{..}`

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \author{You}\thanks{me}

?
```